# Wamp setup - CFIDE - Coldfusion mapping is not working

Tags: coldfusion, wamp

I have Coldfusion, the CF administrator and my test site all setup and working on my local machine using WAMP. The only thing that isn't working is the Coldfusion mappings. For instance if I have the following mapping in the CF admin:

Logical Path         Directory Path

/cfscripts/          E:\wamp\www\CFIDE\scripts\

But when I try to access the path using my local test site http://dev.example.com/cfscripts/ the directory is not found.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong here? It's probably something very straightforward I have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how CF mappings work. CF Mappings are not at the web server level, but are [strictly at the ColdFusion code level](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=basiconfig_10.html).

You need to [set up a virtual directory in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28WS.10%29.aspx) if you want the cfscripts director to be available.