# How to resolve Railo mapping for CSS files

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I set up the following mapping in the admin:

```
Virtual: /css
Resource: /resource/css/v1/
```

Now, how do I resolve this mapping so I can link to my css files?  How can I resolve the `/css` mapping so that I can get `<link href="/resource/css/v1/mycss.css">`?

I went through the system function list but I couldn't find the right function.  Thanks.

Comment: /css/mycss.css should work. But this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163082/wamp-setup-cfide-coldfusion-mapping-is-not-working

Answer (score 7):

The mappings set in Railo admin are not for HTTP requests, they are so the CFML server can locate source code files. They have no bearing on URLs for requests.

CSS requests do not hit the CFML server, they are handled by the web server, so you need to set up a virtual directory on the web server, not a mapping in Railo admin.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  So there is no way for me to access this CF mapping programmatically from the application?

Comment: I don't follow. You're kinda asking whether there's a way to use an apple instead of an orange. I could be being thick, or perhaps it might be an idea to augment your question slightly to give a more demonstrative example of what you're trying to do, and where it's going wrong?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  Let me try again.  Suppose I create a mapping in Application.cfc:  `this.mappings["/css"] = "/resource/css/";`  I know that `<cfinclude template="/css/hello.cfm">` will resolve to `<cfinclude template="/resource/css/hello.cfm">`  but that as you explained `<link href="/css/mycss.css">` won't resolve correctly.  What I am asking is whether there is a way to get access to `this.mappings` struct so I can resolve `/css` to `/resource/css/` myself.

Comment: There is something fundamental I don't quite understand about Application.cfc.  With a regular cfc, I can access its `this` scope through its instantiation.  I had thought that `application` is an instance of Application.cfc, but I can't access application.mappings or application.datasource.

Comment: `getApplicationMetadata()` or possibly `Application.getApplicationSettings()`

Comment: Mappings in CFML are ONLY for referencing within CFML. When you are adding HTML that links to a CSS file, you are NOT using CFML. When you include CSS and JS files in your HTML (using <link> and <script> respectively), they are NOT going through CFML, so the mapping means nothing. As Adam pointed out, you will need to create virtual directories on  your web server to handle these.

Comment: Yup: wot @ScottStroz says. Don't try to solve this in CFML as it's not the right place to solve it. Just create a virtual directory on your web server rather than a mapping on the CF end of things.